# How big of a duct and grill do I need for a central cold air return on a 3 ton system?

Tags: hvac, ducts

What size grill and duct do I need for my cold air return to fit between wall studs in the following scenario?

I have an open-air return in my basement mechanical room with no cold air return ducts or transfer grills.  Thus I'd like to install a cold air return duct to the floor above.

I have a Rheem R96VA0602317MSA 3 ton 56,000 BTU furnace rated for HEATING 1025 CFM @ .2" [.049 kPa] conditioning a 1000 sqft single first floor apartment with 8 foot ceilings.

http://www.deltatms.com/wp-content/uploads/rheem-r96v-spec-sheet.pdf

I'd like to punch up through the ceiling of the mechanical room above the furnace and add a cold air return.

How big of a grill and duct do I need for the cold air return?  Looking online at some calculators it seems like I need 421 sq inch grill - but is that for a supply?  Using another calculator, I have 8000 sqft of total air volume with 6 changes an hour which suggests a 2.5 ton system, but since I already have the spec saying 1025 cfm in a 3 ton system should I just go off the 3 ton 1025 cfm value I have?  Another calculator says I need 360 sq inches of grille?

I couldn't find calculators on return duct size - just supply total duct area.  What duct size do I need if it only travels 9 feet, from basement to ceiling?  I'd like the duct and grill to be something that can fit between wall studs so that I can have it come up into an interior wall on the first floor.

Comment: You must accommodate at least the minimum size duct and grill for the cfm of the air handler

Comment: https://learnmetrics.com/cfm-duct-sizing-chart/.  If using flex round duct 18” will accommodate  16” is slightly undersized

Comment: What size for rigid rectangular duct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 ton makes no sense when talking about a furnace. Ton is a measure of A/C capacity and your blower motor needs 400 CFM per ton. If you have paired this furnace with a 3 ton A/C unit then that is a big mistake. 2.5 ton would be the correct size.

Anyways, your furnace maxes out at 1,025 CFM so you need one of the following:

- 16" flex duct (this is rated for 1,000 cfm so it should be fine)
- 16" rigid duct (this is rated for 1,200 cfm but 15" doesn't exist)
- 18"x12" rigid rectangle duct (rated for 1,100 cfm)

If you plan to use a standard wall cavity with 2x4s 16" on center then you would have to run six 14x4 ducts through the walls or seven 12x4s.

[duct size calculator](https://hvacdirect.com/hvac/pdf/Field_duct-sizing-chart.pdf)

Your return should match the supply, period.

Comment: If I use an 18X12" rectangle duct to the plenum from the ceiling, what kind of "boot" would I need?  I think I can pop up into the back of a closet but would need to angle my way 45 degrees to the back of perpendicular wall adjacent to the closet to cut out the vent opening...

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey Plenums are usually oversized so a reducer is common. You need a local sheet metal shop to fabricate the desired transition piece (reducer). I only chose 18x12 for my example because it was convenient on that chart. You should pick your duct size based on whatever size grill is available; usually they are square. You can get away with a 14x14 duct but 15x15 would be best. The grill is usually larger than the duct.

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey For example, the plenum on my furnace is 17x20 (1,930 cfm) which is way oversized for the 1,200 cfm motor so I had a transition piece fabricated for my trunk.

Comment: Looking at its twin unit with a return - I see that the other unit has an 8x22 rectangular duct for the return - is that undersized?

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey Look at the duct size calculator which I linked. If you can't make heads or tails of it then you should hire a professional.

Comment: understand the calculator - but it's the contradictions I'm confused by - 8x22 suggests 840cfm which seems less than what the blower is rated for, so wondering if I'm missing something when I read the specs of my unit.  I'd prefer to hire, but, unfortunately, I've already reached out to many pros, and no help from professionals I reached out to in the city.  None of the dozen HVAC people I found in my area want to do any work with ducts in existing installations for some reason.  They only want to do commercial work or new construction.

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey Are you 100% certain that it's a twin? If so then the return is undersized by about 185 CFM (18%). The only way to properly check whether an HVAC system was designed correctly is to perform a static pressure test.

Comment: Yeah it's an identical model, but it services twice the sq footage, 2200sqft for 2nd and 3rd floors.  I'll see if they can do a static pressure test.

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey Oh wow, either you live in a warmer climate than I do, NY, or you have a very well insulated home. 56k btu might be drastically undersized for 2200sqft, but then again I guess this might be part of why you're adding a furnace? 56k is just about right for 1000sqft.

Comment: I'm in NYC queens, so... same weather lol

Comment: The furnaces are already existing so not adding new, one was for 2nd and 3rd floor while the other was for the 1st floor only.  Each floor is about 1100 sqft.  Just looking to fix the return flow to the 1st floor serving unit.

Comment: if you are in NY - know of any good HVAC and duct people you recommend?  I haven't been able to find anyone with good knowledge through google.

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey Sorry but I'm in Central NY, quite a bit away from you. I've experienced the same attitude though when I was getting quoted for some HVAC work; they'd rather do a new install. It's especially difficult since it's now officially December so I'm sure HVAC folks have more work than they can handle right now; or at least that's the excuse they readily use. If you're having a difficult time sourcing ductwork then seek out a local sheet metal shop and tell them the sizes you need. Provide pictures of your existing furnace so they know if the flange has to be special in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Minimizing flow restriction on the suction side of a fan improves efficiency, so bigger is better. I have over 1000 square inches of filter area (duct is larger) for a 5 ton AC. I think it is more a matter of "how big can you make it" than what minimum will work.

Comment: Well I have very limited space since I have to make it fit between another system and a lot of existing ductwork - the grill I can probably make pretty big, but the actual ducts have to squeeze past some joists, studs and other pipe, so looking for the minimum thinest size